# Custom archive and paging

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can anyone please explain this seemingly odd wordpress behaviour please?

I have `blog pages show at most` set to 10 under `settings->reading` - this is the default.

I have a custom post type for `exhibitors` and I have created 7 of these.

On the archive page for exhibitors `archive-exhibitors.blade.php` I only want to display 2 at a time so I'm using the code as follows:

```
@php
    global $wp_query;
    $posts_per_page = 2 ;
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if(!$paged){
        $paged = 1;
    }
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'exhibitors',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged,
    ];
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

@endphp

@while (have_posts()) @php the_post() @endphp
@include('partials.content-'.get_post_type())
@endwhile
```

Now when I go to `/exhibitors/` I'm seeing the first 2 exhibors listed as you'd expect, but when I go to `/exhibitors/page/2/` I am actually getting my 404 page.

If I reset `blog posts to show at most` to 5, I can go to `/exhibitors/page/2/` and I see the 3rd and 4th posts as you'd expect, but now page 3 doesn't work. I can only get this to work correctly if I set `blog posts to show at most` to 1.

I don't really understand why this is occuring, it's like there's some pre-query thing going on which is looking at the global setting, and redirecting to the 404, which in this case is incorrect.

Any help gratefully accepted

Comment: Have you tested first re-saving the permalinks? Settings->Permalinks. Then re-test.

Comment: @David.J yes I have, that was my initial thought too.

Comment: Maybe a slug conflict, ie a page with the same slug as your custom post type?

Comment: Change your global to: ``global $post,$paged;`` and change your paged variable to ``$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;``

Comment: Tried that @David.J doesn't solve it I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, not a solution! I'm just posting this here so it may help others. I my `functions.php` I have just added this:

```
function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive('exhibitors') ) {
        if(!is_admin()){
            set_query_var('posts_per_page', 1);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

This seems to override the default `blog posts to show` setting and you can do it on a per post_type basis. Note, I'm checking it's not an admin page because this is just for the front end.

Anyone know of a better solution??